# Julia Module LoadError: UndefVarError when trying to use a local module in a script

Tags: module, scripting, julia

I'm trying to use a Julia module in a local script, but I'm encountering an "*UndefVarError: ModuleA not defined*" error. Here's the structure of my project:

```
- dir/
  - Julia/
    - Code/
```

**ModuleA.jl**:

```
module ModuleA

export PI

# Define some variables
const PI = 3.14159265359
Variable1 = "Value1"
Variable2 = 34

# Define some function
function square(x)
    return x^2
end

# Define another function
function greet(name)
    println("My name is $name.")
end

end
```

**ProgramABC.jl**:

```
using .ModuleA

# Access the variables
println("The value of PI is $PI")
```

I'm running the program in */Code* directory with the command:

```
julia ProgramABC.jl
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: ModuleA not defined in expression starting at /home/***/dir/Julia/Code/ProgramABC.jl:1
```

I've double-checked the filenames, ensured that both files are in the same directory, and there don't seem to be any syntax errors in ModuleA.jl. What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you are trying to do, might be possible, but is generally not recommended. Julia project are usually using a specific structure. Look into the excellent documentation of Pkg.jl https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/ (especially the part on creating packages)

Comment: What should I do if I have some common functions and variable constants in my Project. What should be my approach? Should I use Packages or Modules?

Comment: Packages are the way how to structure your code, also using modules. Every package contains at least one module. So you'd write your own little package with a module inside it, and then your script could load that package. Either by finding it in the same folder, or by making use of the package manager / environment system.